# TypeScript template isn't in the "Add New Item" dialog in visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I just installed Visual studio 2015 enterprise. I want to add a Type Script file to my project but as you can you can see in the bellow screenshot, Type Script template is not in the "Add New Item" dialog.
When I open a type script file, intellisense is not working and all the code is shown in white color.
I've installed "TypeScript_Dev14Full.exe" but the problem still exist.
[click here to see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXV3M.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem in *Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition* and it started showing typescript template in add new item list after updating it to *Visual Studio Update 3*.
You can download that 3rd update from:
`Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates`

Answer (score 0):

I am using V 2015 Community edition and i have also face this problem after direct install TypeScript for VS2015 from its official site.Please install TypeScript first for VS2015.

In my case i am creating a New Web Site Application from

```
      Goto File -> New - > Website
```

thats why TypeScript file not displaying in SolutionExplorer.
I recommend you please create New Project and Select Asp.Net Website from there

```
        Goto File -> New - > Project
```

then you will be able to add TypeScript File from there. 
If nothing happens please let me know